# How to Parse JsonArray?

Tags: android, json

Can you help me with this

how can i parse this Json Array. i'm getting error type mismatch

Thanks  in  Advance.

```
{"response": [
{
  "feed": [
    {
      "rating": 1,
      "lname": "",
      "surname": "xxxxx",
      "date": "2015-04-05 102:51:35",
      "details": "check"
    },
    {
      "rating": 2,
      "name": "",
      "avatar": ""          
    }
  ]
}]}
```

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to serialise

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(<your response>);
```

incase you are getting your response as a json object you can ignore the above.

next

```
 jsonArray responseArray= jsonObject.getJsonArray("response");
 jsonObject feedObject = responseArray[0];
 jsonArray feedArray = feedObject.getJsonArray("feed");
```

Now that you have your feedArray you can traverse it to get all its data.